# Is there a way to map validator pubkeys to the name of validator on Solana JSON RPC?

Tags: blockchain, rpc, web3js, solana

Is there any JSON RPC method (or any package I can use) to get the name of the validators on Solana rather than only the pubkey. The `getVoteAccounts` method (https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getvoteaccounts) on the JSON RPC returns validator info but returns the validator pubkeys only, not the name.

For instance, how can I map the pubkey `beefKGBWeSpHzYBHZXwp5So7wdQGX6mu4ZHCsH3uTar` to Coinbase Cloud ?

Answer (score 2):

The validator information is stored in accounts owned by "Config1111111111111111111111111111111111111".

To get this info you can use a call such as:

```
curl https://api.testnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getProgramAccounts",
    "params": [
      "Config1111111111111111111111111111111111111",
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed"
      }
    ]
  }
' | jq
```

Check the documentation for the RPC method to adjust your request: https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getprogramaccounts